# Reference for Bruhat-Whitney's complexification of a real analytic manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

I'm trying to learn a bit about Grauert Tubes, and in my reading I frequently encounter references to a result of Bruhat-Whitney in this paper: "Quelques propriétés fondamentales des ensembles analytiques-réels." I'd like to understand this existence of complexifications more concretely, but unfortunately I cannot read french. Does anyone have recommendations for where I can read more about their proof?

Comment: See comments at [Off-diagonal holomorphic extension of real analytic functions on $\mathbb{C}^n \times\mathbb{C}^n$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/142915/off-diagonal-holomorphic-extension-of-real-analytic-functions-on-mathbbcn)

Comment: Hi, thank you very much! This is just what I was looking for.